# String of Number with comma

Tags: java

I am having issues when solving this problem:

> Write a structures program that can accept two integer numbers up to 40 digit and perform the following:
>
> 1. add the two numbers together and display the result
> 2. the result number should should be seperated by commas.

So I was able to do number 1 using `BigInteger`, but for part 2 I am having issues. I don't know how I'm supposed to add a comma to a string, I was using a `for` loop to do with split but its not working.

I was able to figure it out thanks for all the help

```
   public static String NewString (String num)
   {
    String sent = "" ;
    int count = 0;
        for ( int index = num.length()-1 ; index >= 0 ; index --)
        {
       count++;
           sent = num.charAt(index) + sent;
       if(count % 3 == 0 && index != 0) 
       sent = "," + sent;
        }
      return sent;
   }
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you have so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
String formattedInteger = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(bigInteger);
```

or you can write your own. It would be pretty simple, just convert your `BigInteger` to a `String` then loop through it backwards and every 3rd character you pass add a comma.

Answer (score 0):

The code below -

- Adds two numbers together and displays the result
- The result number should be separated by commas.

Is quite self explanatory, Hope this helps :)

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 * Created by Nick on 11/13/14.
 *
 * Add two numbers together and display the result
 * The result number should be separated by commas.
 */
public class SO_26916958 {

private static BigInteger arg1;
private static BigInteger arg2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    arg1 = new BigInteger (args[0].getBytes());
    arg2 = new BigInteger (args[1].getBytes());
    BigInteger sum = arg1.add(arg2);
    String bigIntegerString = sum.toString();

    String output = recursivelyAddComma(bigIntegerString);

    System.out.print(bigIntegerString +"\n");
    System.out.print(output);
}

private static String recursivelyAddComma (String s) {
    int length = s.length();
    StringBuilder output = null;

    if(length <= 3) {
        return s.toString();
    }

    return  recursivelyAddComma(s.substring(0, length - 3)).concat(",").concat(s.substring(length - 3, length));

    }

}
```